# Can't filter on dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Following some tutorials I am trying to filter my data by dates selected from a dropdown menu. I have set my date column as the index and tested that all the values are of type datetime but I am receiving the following error:

```
TypeError("'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'",)
```

Data:

```
CustomerName,OrderDate,Item,ItemSKU,Price,Quantity,Channel,Total
Joe,Blog,26/09/2018,Rocks,Rock001,10.99,10,Amazon,100.99
Joe,Blog,26/08/2018,Rocks,Rock001,10.99,10,Amazon,100.99
Joe,Blog,26/07/2018,Rocks,Rock001,10.99,10,Amazon,100.99
```

Code:
Values year, month are returned from user selection

```
firstDayMonth = datetime.date(year, month, 1)
daysHolder = monthrange(year, month)
lastDayMonth = datetime.date(year, month, daysHolder[1])

df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/testData.csv")
gb = df.groupby(['Channel'])
Amz = gb.get_group('Amazon')
df = Amz .set_index(Amz ['OrderDate'])
df['OrderDate'] = df['OrderDate'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
newData = df.loc[firstDayMonth:lastDayMonth]
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Try `df['OrderDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OrderDate'])
newData = df.loc[pd.Timestamp(firstDayMonth):pd.Timestamp(lastDayMonth)]`

Comment: @John Zwinck this line - newData = `df.loc[firstDayMonth:lastDayMonth]`

Comment: Interestingly its showing `df['OrderDate']` as an object now even after using to_datetime to change the data type

Answer (score 1):

So it seems I just need to switch the order of the dates in the slice. Using `newData = df.loc[lastDayMonth:firstDayMonth]` but `newData = df.loc[firstDayMonth:lastDayMonth]` doesnt work. I think this is due to in my data my data is decending from latest date to oldest.

Answer (score 0):

While you do set the index to the OrderDate column, you do so *before* you set the type of that column to datetime.  You probably need to change the type before using the column as the index, otherwise your indexing with `loc` fails.

Comment: I gave this a try, still returning the same error unfortunately